# Meeting Request to Partner Portal Users

Tags: email-template, partner-portal

I am using the standard meeting request out-of-the-box solution of Salesforce to conduct meeting between internal users and partner users. Now, when a internal user creates a meeting request, an email is sent to all invitees  automatically by Salesforce itself. When a recipent is a partner user we need the email to go with the partner portal URL. The following email is sent to a Partner User, after an internal user has confirmed a meeting at a specific date & time.

See the screenshot attached[image: Meeting Request Screenshot]

In the screenshot, notice the URL below the "Respond to This Request" button.
You can see that the URL belongs to our Salesforce org. But this email is being sent to a partner user. When I login as a Partner User and click on this link, it takes me to Salesforce login page. When i just take the id from the end of the URL and try to open it in the Partner Portal, it opens up the Multi Person Calendar Event where i can accept or decline the event. Is there a way to customize this standard email template so that, for partner portal users, the  URL has the Partner Portal URL in the email ??